# Как в regex можно "запомнить" значение знака?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Я пытаюсь решить эту [задачу](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/validating-postalcode/problem).
Мне нужно найти паттерн в шестизначной цифре где цифра повторяется через одну.
Например:

```
1.1....
.2.2...
....5.5
```

`.`: любая цифра.

Есть ли в регулярных выражениях возможность запоминать прочитанный знак? Или проверить одинаковы ли два знака?

Используется regex engine от python. Но я предполагаю что ответ будет универсальным.

Comment: /(1\d1)|(2\d2)|(3\d3)|(4\d4)|(5\d5)|(6\d6)|(7\d7)|(8\d8)|(9\d9)|(0\d0)/ - Мне кажется это решение в лоб

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис спасибо, я решил задачу. Ваш вариант мне тоже нравится, но мой более компактный.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, ужОс - представил себе ваше решение для случая если надо было искать повтор трёхзначных или более чисел

Answer (score 2):

Я решил задачу. Ответ

```
^.*(\d).\1.*$
```

- `^` начало строки
- `.*` любое количество знаков
- `(\d)` одна цифра в виде группы (первая группа)
- `.` один знак
- `\1` "то же самое что и в первой группе", т.е. то же самое число
- `.*` любое количество знаков
- `$` конец строки